# using pulp ,Choosing a project according to some constraint

Tags: python, machine-learning, data-science, pulp, pulpcore

```
|project|loc_Bangalore|loc_Pune|cat_s|cat_c|
|:------|:-----------:|:------:|:---:|:---:|
|abc    |1            |0       |0    |1    |
|Sys    |1            |0       |0    |1    |
|Syst   |0            |1       |1    |0    |
|EPS    |1            |0       |0    |1    |
|foss   |1            |0       |0    |1    |
|opc    |0            |1       |1    |0    |
```

**given**

> In above df 1 is true and 0 is false.
> I have to choose all project from given df,which satisfied below condition:
> 1.total project choosed count<=4((banglore location project+pune location
> project+cat_s project+cat_c project)<=4)
>
> 2.In choosed project project count should be following:
> 1.banglore location project<=3
> 2.pune location project <=1
> 3.cat_s project<=1
> 4.cat_c project<=3

i have to select project which will satisfy both the condition.
i am not able to write equation for this.Pls help me in solving this.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are close.  You didn't show what answer you are getting from above, but my guess is that you are getting a bunch of wild integer values, including negative ones because your decision variable has no bounds, so it could be selecting -568 projects in area __.

First issue:
When the variable represents a yes/no type of decision, you should make it a binary variable.  Change this:

```
proj_vars = pulp.LpVariable.dicts("project",project_list,cat='Integer')
```

to:

```
proj_vars = pulp.LpVariable.dicts("project",project_list,cat='Binary')
```

Second issue:
right now, you are missing an objective function...  all you have are a bunch of "upper constraints" and the model (at least the piece you posted) has no motivation to increase (or assign) projects.  You have it as a minimization model....  What are you minimizing?

From what you describe, you appear to want to do the *maximum* number of projects, subject to your constraints.  So to do that you must:  add a simple objective that is just the sum of the projects, and flip the problem into a maximization problem.  Make sense?

Comment: you are correct for the variable,but i am not able to write the objective function.will you pls help me in this?